# How do I make it so that while a key is pressed and another key is released an action occurs? (Pygame/python)

Tags: python, pygame, key

So basically I'm making a quiz game in which the user must "lock in" their answer. In order to do that the user must press a certain key while pressing another. For example: holding the "w" key while pressing and letting go of the space bar.But when I try to achieve this, nothing happens. Here is what I have so far:

```
if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN) and (event.key == pygame.K_w) and (event.type == pygame.KEYUP) and (event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
    print(1)
```

why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed). Example -

```
keys = pygame.keys.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_w] and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    print(1)
```

EDIT : This is how I implemented it -

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit


#initializing variables
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480),0,24)
pygame.display.set_caption("Key Press Test")
f1=pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",24)

#main loop which displays the pressed keys on the screen
while True:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        a=100
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        if pygame.key.get_focused():
            press=pygame.key.get_pressed()

            # checking if they are pressed at the same time or not.
            if press[pygame.K_w] and press[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                print (1)
            for i in xrange(0,len(press)):
                if press[i]==1:
                    name=pygame.key.name(i)
                    text=f1.render(name,True,(0,0,0))
                    screen.blit(text,(100,a))
                    a=a+100
            pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    question_num = general_knowlege_questions[0]
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and (General_knowledge[question_num][5] == "a"):
        test = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and (General_knowledge[question_num][5] == "b"):
        test = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and (General_knowledge[question_num][5] == "c"):
        test = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and (General_knowledge[question_num][5] == "d"):
        test = 1
```

so basically this is my code to recognize my answer for the quiz, but it ends up not recognizing the correct answer. Btw the General_knowledge variable is a list, question number is self explanitory and 5 is the index that contains the answer.

Comment: NVM I FINALLY GOT IT